# Tickera missing attendees - No attendees found

Tags: plugins, php, custom-post-types

I transferred a wordpress site to azure (app-service hosted on linux with php 8.2). One of the errors was related to `freemius` used by `tickera`. The site was not loading. It was fixed with that [plugin](https://github.com/Freemius/freemius-fixer). But after a while I noticed that attendees were missing (Tickera -> Attendees & Tickets, *~/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=tc_tickets_instances*):

[image: missing data]

I enabled debug as per [documentation](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/), wp-content/debug.log is missing, ~/error_log no errors, also in wp-content/uploads no related error.

According to the query below it returns ~1300 records with status "publish":

```sql
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_type = 'tc_tickets_instances';
```

The same steps related to freemius-fixer was executed locally, but there it shows attendees data.

Any ideas what to check, how to fix ?

Comment: You'll have to ask the plugin's support team about this. Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: I thought it could be some setting in wordpress, yeah it's a custom post type, but doesn't sure why it's not working. It's just like a "post" but with different meta data.